# Make a boxes that contain text but it only display the text

Tags: html, css

So i try to make a box , for each data that has in the database (the data already been load in views)

here's the html

```
    <div id="edit" class="tab-pane">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 detailed">
                            <h4 class="mb">List of Campaign</h4>
                                {% for table in obj2 %}
                                        <div class="boxes">
                                              {{table}}
                                        </div>
                                {% endfor %} 

                              </div>

                          </div>
                          <!-- /col-lg-8 -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /row -->
                      </div>
```

here's the css

```
.boxes
{
  border:10px solid black;
}
```

but it  only display the list of data , without the border , am i wrong about the css? i thought it's already right

Edit :
full html code

```
<section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper site-min-height">

               <!-- <div class="profile-pic">
                  <p><img src="img/ui-sam.jpg" class="img-circle"></p>
                -->
                  <!-- <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-theme"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Follow</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-theme02">Add</button>
                  </p> 

          <!-- /col-lg-12 -->
          <div class="col-lg-12 mt">
            <div class="row content-panel">
              <!-- /panel-heading -->
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div id="overview" class="tab-pane active">
                  <!-- /tab-pane -->

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 detailed">
                        <h4 class="mb">List of Campaign</h4>
                            {% for table in obj2 %}
                                    <div class="boxes">
                                          {{table}}
                                    </div>
                            {% endfor %} 
                              </div>


                      </div>
                      <!-- /col-lg-8 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /row -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /tab-pane -->
                </div>
                <!-- /tab-content -->
              </div>
              <!-- /panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /col-lg-12 -->
          </div>
          <!-- /row -->
        </div>        
        <!-- /container -->
      </section>
      <!-- /wrapper -->

    </section>
```

this edit is the full html code

Comment: check for css override using inspect element

Comment: Check the DOM elements. After rendering in the browser if the css overriden by some other css class. Use !important with the css class then.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add CSS on **td** and **th** Use below CSS

```
.boxes td, .boxes th{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: why should add td and th

Comment: Because you want a border on every row so you need to add CSS on the child, not on the parent

Comment: oh sry , i mean , in my html i dont have any table in it , and the {[ table }} is just a variable

Comment: Okay, then  add a border on class **.boxes** and  add **display: block** property with border